# why is my select option is disabled in webpage

Tags: javascript, contentful

I have a problem with my select option. I used Contentful model to fetch my data. In the content model, I have given the fields except the select option field. Kindly help me out with this. Here is the code:

```
    products.forEach(product => {
        result += `<div class="millet-column">

                <div class="img-container">
                    <img src=${product.image}>
                    <button class="bag-btn" data-id=${product.id}>
                        <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        Add to Bag
                    </button>
                </div>

                <p class="item-name">
                    ${product.title}
                </p>
                <p class="item-category">
                    ${product.category}
                </p>

                <br>
                <h2 style="float:left;margin-left:3%;margin-top:-2%;"> Rs.</h2>
                <div class="total-price">${product.price}</div>
                <select id="list" data-price="${product.price}" name="quantity" class="product-select" tabindex="1"
                onchange="getSelectValue();">
                    <option value="250">250 g</option>
                    <option value="500">500 g</option>
                    <option value="1000">1 kg</option>
                </select>
            </div>`
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.